# Copying XML element from one file to another using command line

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xml-parsing

How can I copy an element together with any content it has from a XML file to another using a command-line tool?

For example, is there a way to copy all the content from file X below to file Y using a command such as "copy to file-y.mynotes from file-x.note" ?

File X:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

File Y:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mynotes>

  <!-- The content of file X here -->

  <note>
    <to>Tove2</to>
    <from>Jani2</from>
    <heading>Reminder2</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend2!</body>
  </note>

  <note>
    <to>Tove3</to>
    <from>Jani3</from>
    <heading>Reminder3</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!3</body>
  </note>

<mynotes>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult but can be done with xidel:

```
xidel  file_y.xml --xquery 'let $abc := (./mynotes/note) \
let $def := doc("file_x.xml")//*[1] return insert-before($abc, 0, $def)' --output-format xml
```